# Unable to resolve service for type 'DataAccesssLayer.DataLogic.IRepoDll' while attempting to activate 'BusinessAccess.Repo.RepoBll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Here im using N-Tier Architecture as
DLL--->"IRepoDll,RepoDll",

BLL-->"IRepoBll,RepoBll",

Models-->all Db Model,

ViewMode---> all ViewModl,

PresentationLayer---> Here I'm Using WebApi

Here MY Archticture is  UI<=====>Bll<=====>Dll<=====>DataBase
Please Help me why I'm not able to reach my Dll
In Ui layer
**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");

    services.AddScoped<IRepoBll, RepoBll>();
}
```

**HomeController**

```
 private readonly IRepoBll Orepo;
        public HomeController(IRepoBll _repo)
        {
            this.Orepo = _repo;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("MyData")]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetData()
        {
            var x = this.Orepo.GetEmployee();
            return null;
        }
```

**Bll code**

```
public class RepoBll : IRepoBll
    {
        private readonly IRepoDll Orepo;
        public RepoBll(IRepoDll _orepo){
            this.Orepo = _orepo;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee()
        {
            var x = this.Orepo.GetCastRecords();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Dll code**

```
public class RepoDll : IRepoDll
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _Context;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public RepoDll(DatabaseContext _Context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this._Context = _Context;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Tbl_Cast> GetCastRecords()
        {
            var x = (from n in _Context.Tbl_Cast
                           orderby n.Cast_Id
                           select n).ToList();
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the full ConfigureServices method from startup.cs? Not just the one line      `services.AddScoped<IRepoBll, RepoBll>();`

Comment: @LinkedListT i Updated my code as void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

Comment: The issue may be caused because you are resolving the service for IRepoBLL but you haven't registered IRepoDLL in startup. IRepoDLL service isn't getting injected in BLL code `public RepoBll(IRepoDll _orepo`

Comment: @linkedlisrT tq soo much for your valuable answer...  After adding irepodll,repodll in startup.cs class it's working

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because you are resolving the service for IRepoBLL but you haven't registered IRepoDLL in Startup.cs. IRepoDLL service isn't getting injected in BLL code `public RepoBll(IRepoDll _orepo)`. Add this to Startup.cs `services.AddScoped<IRepoDll, RepoDll>();` and should work.

Answer (score -1):

- You might using one of this dependency injection process i guess, if
  not you can prepare custom dependency injection process, it will
  work,
- UnityContainer
- Castle Windsor
- NInject
- Structure Map

Comment: This is a suggestion for alternatives, not an answer to OP's direct problem.